# Why does Harewood blow up the Starfleet facility after using Harrison's blood to save his daughter?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In the beginning of Star Trek Into Darkness, Thomas Harewood is shown using John Harrison's blood to save his daughter in the hospital.

After seeing that it worked - he then proceeds to drop a ring into a glass of water setting off a bomb that kills himself and presumably hundreds of others.

What makes Thomas keep his promise to Harrison? **What prevents him from simply seeing Harrison as a criminal, breaking the deal, becoming a fugitive from Harrison, and leaving town with his wife and daughter instead of going forward with killing hundreds of his co-workers and leaving his family without a husband and a father?**

Answer (score 4):

The very short answer is that Harewood is mortally afraid of Harrison. He seems to be aware of Harewood's true identity, and hence would be aware of his personal capabilities, monstrous intellect and capacity for unreasoned violence.

> ***Given what he had managed to learn about the individual who had
> provided both vial and ring, he knew he should have expected nothing
> less.***

If he fails to keep up his end of the bargain, the clear implication is that Harrison will track him down with consumnate ease, killing him and his family wherever they try to run and hide. Note that (at least according to the novel) he does *briefly toy with the idea of not going through with it*, but then he sees Harrison in the street and decides against it.

> *Across the street stood the man with whom he had struck the bargain. The man who had somehow, in defiance of everything Harewood and his wife had been told, saved their daughter from a slow, certain death. He was watching. Quietly, calmly, without the slightest sign or suggestion of concern.*
>
> *Harewood turned and entered the building. The arcade was old, perhaps
> eighteenth century. He was resigned now. At peace with himself. **Renege
> on the agreement, and the miracle for which he was about to trade
> everything might evaporate, its promise never to be fulfilled.** That
> was what he had been told, anyway, and he had no choice but to follow
> through on the last of his instructions. That was the warning Harewood
> had been given.*

There's also a certain element of personal pride at play here. He's made a bargain (albeit with the devil) and he's going to see it through.

> *Can’t back out now, he thought. It didn’t matter. **He had long since
> resolved to see the matter through to its end. It was not about him,
> anyway.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek Into Darkness - Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness_(novel))</sup></sub>